# Sufficient conditions to be a covariance

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Given a function, $c(x,y):\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, what are sufficient conditions for this to be the covariance of some (centered) Gaussian random field $X:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$,
$$
c(x,y) = \mathbb{E}[X(x)X(y)]
$$
Obviously, we would like $c$ to be symmetric, $c(x,y) =c(y,x)$, but what is also needed is that it be positive definite.  I know there is Bochner's theorem, which relates $c$ to the Fourier transform of a positive measure, but my real question is, for closed form choices of $c$, are there simple conditions that can be easily checked (*i.e.* $c$ decays sufficiently rapidly as $|x-y|\to \infty$)?

**EDIT**: What I am really asking is, if I write down a simple function, like
$$
c(x,y) = \frac{1}{1+|x-y|^p}, \quad p>0
$$
is there a way to tell, by inspection, whether or not there exists a Gaussian random field with this as its covariance kernel.  I mention positive definiteness because, in my mind, it is not obvious how to check that
$$
(Cf)(x) = \int c(x,y) f(y)dy,\quad f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})
$$
is a positive definite operator.

**ALSO**, I am not strictly wedded to working with $\mathbb{R}$.  If there is a clear answer to this problem when $c:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb{R}$, I would be interested to hear that too.

Comment: You say $X$ is a "random variable" but then you write $X(x)$.  Do you mean that $X$ is a stochastic process indexed by $\mathbb{R}$?  A stochastic process indexed by an uncountable set is a nasty object without further assumptions (e.g. cadlag); what do you want to impose here?

Comment: It is not clear what question you are asking. Is it what conditions on $c$ are required to make it a covariance of some random process (as the title suggests) or are you interested in criteria for positive definite functions (as the last paragraph suggests) ? Maybe you can rephrase your question to make this clear.

Comment: I tried to clarify this.  1. I am really thinking of Gaussian random fields.  2.  In my mind, it is the positive definiteness of a given kernel that is the tough part to check.  Perhaps that is incorrect.

Comment: In concrete examples, it is easy to _disprove_ that a kernel of the form $c(x, y) = f(|x-y|)$ is positive definite, by computing the Fourier transform of $f$ up to some accuracy and looking for negative values.

Comment: The footnote on page 6 here may be of interest: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~jtaylo/courses/stats352/notes/random_fields.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polya's criterion says that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is even, convex on $[0,\infty)$, with $f(0)>0$ and zero limit at infinity, then $c(x,y) = f(\vert x-y\vert)$ is a positive definite kernel, hence the existence of the Gaussian random field. It would apply to your function for $p$ less than $1$ for example (to be checked).

Comment: I don't think it applies to the OP's function for all $p > 0$, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+fourier+transform+of+1%2F%281%2Bx%5E4%29+for+omega+between+-10+and+10

Comment: yes right, added a correction

Comment: The kernel I wrote down was just for example, but this is exactly the sort of test I was looking for.